# Web Mapping SNMP polling and databases

Tags: web-mapping, api

I am doing a project that involves Web Mapping.

The project involves having a simulated communications network for a wind turbine company.

My project involves building a user front end to display the health of each turbine on the map.

I will be using using [Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) to poll [Management Information Bases (MIBs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management_information_base) for performance, and a few databases to enrich the data that will be then displayed on the map.

I am trying to understand the most efficient protocol i can use to display the info that is stored in the monitoring databases (e.g. HTTP, SOAP, REST, JSON, OSLC, etc) as displaying this info quickly is vital.

Would anyone have any suggestions on which to use for such circumstances?

Comment: I would guess that sending the results to client would take a fraction of a second with any protocol. If you do not need to care about milliseconds you can freely select the protocol that suits best with the general architecture used in the enterprise.